# LinQ to Entities: Query with four tables JOIN

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have four tables:

```
- Client with PK ClientID.
- Destination with PK DestinationID.
- Language with PK LanguageID.
- DestinationDetail with PK DestinationID.
- RL-Client-Destination with PKs ClientID and DestinationID.
```

The Client may have zero or n Destinations. A destination has n DestinationDetails, each of these DestinationDetail has a language.

Ok. I need to retrieve all of DestinationDetails for a given client and a given language.

I start writing this:

```
try
   {
      ObjectQuery clientes = 
          guiaContext.Cliente;
      ObjectQuery destinos =
          guiaContext.Destino;
      ObjectQuery idiomas =
          guiaContext.Idioma;
      ObjectQuery detalles =
          guiaContext.DetalleDestino;

      IQueryable detalleQuery =
          from cliente in clientes
          from destino in destinos
          from idioma in idiomas
          from detalleDestino in detalles
          where destino.
          select detalleDestino;

   }
   catch
   {
   }
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its along the lines:

```
var detalleQuery =
          from client in guiaContext.Clients
          where client.ID == 1
          from destination in cliente.Destinations
          from destinationDetail in destination.DestionationDetails
          where destinationDetail.Language.Iso2Code == "es"
          select destinationDetail;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing linq joins:

[Select from multiple table using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433/linq-select-with-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
var db = new PracticeEntities();
            var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
                Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
                dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

Thanks!