# Linq query to select data from table and join 2 tables

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to `select` everything from a table and then make a join with two other tables, from which I need just some of the columns. The final list will be populated into a `DevExpress GridControl`. The main table that I take the data from has these columns:

```
Id | ScheduleId | AccountId | Description
```

I can easily select everything from this table and return. Here is my list:

```
public IList<StatusDescription> getStatusDescription()
{
    var listOfItems = from e in context.StatusDescription select e;
    return listOfItems.ToList<StatusDescription>();
}
```

The other two tables are Schedules and Accounts, they look as follows:

```
Id | ScheduleName | DateFrom | DateTo
```

and

```
Id | AccountName | AccountCode
```

I would like to join the `DateFrom` and `DateTo` from the `Schedule` table and the `AccountCode` from the `Account` table. Is it possible to get all that into a single list. I can easily bind it later to the `GridControl`

Comment: I don't see any problem, have a look at the following http://stackoverflow.com/a/32465/1099716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var listOfItems = from e in context.StatusDescription
                  join s in context.Schedules on e.ScheduleId equals s.Id
                  join a in context.Accounts on e.AccountId equals a.Id
                  select new 
                  {
                      Description = e.Description,
                      ScheduleStart = s.DateFrom,
                      ScheduleEnd = s.DateTo,
                      AccountCode = a.AccountCode
                  }
```

Comment: I accepted the answer because it is a solution to the question. But do you know what should the return type be, because trying to return `IList<StatusDescription>` gives an error(I understand why it does it).

Comment: @Ivo In the example the return type is an anonymous object, if you need to return a specific type then you would need to create a type which accommodates those particular fields `select new QueryType { ... }`. You can't expect `StatusDescription` because it doesn't have properties like `ScheduleStart` / `ScheduleEnd` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I was hoping to avoid creating a new class, but it's done now.

Answer (score 0):

`var Query = from p in context.StatusDescription
                    select new
                    {
                        p.Id,
                        p.Description,
                        p.Schedule.DateFrom,
                        p.Schedule.DateTo,
                        p.Account.AccountCode
                    };`

hope it helps

Comment: yes this is a simple select and it mean's we do not need 'join' in this case :)