# C# - Database context cast return

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, api, dbcontext

I am currently using Asp.net database context to create a API, and I came into a problem. I have two Database Tables and I want to output some of the data but **not all of it**

My tables:

```
Employee Table:
+----+------+---------------+------------+---------------+
| Id | Name |     Mail      |   Phone    |   Birthday    |
+----+------+---------------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | John | John@Mail.com | 987 72 123 | 25-July  2000 |
|  2 | Stan | Stan@Mail.com | 978 21 342 | 10-April 1998 |
|  3 | Kim  | Kim@Mail.com  | 973 28 199 | 26-March 2001 |
+----+------+---------------+------------+---------------+

Shift Table:
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| EmployeeId |       Start        |        End         | Active |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|     1      | 10-June 2019 08:00 | 10-June 2019 16:00 |  true  |
|     2      | 10-June 2019 12:00 | 10-June 2019 18:00 |  true  |
|     3      | 10-June 2019 16:00 | 11-June 2019 00:00 |  true  |
|     2      | 11-June 2019 08:00 | 11-June 2019 16:00 |  true  |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

*In my tables the Employee Table and Shift Table have a 1-Many relationship between Employee.Id and Shift.Id*

Using the controller I have created i have been able to return all of the data, however I want to return a specific data-set (**not everything**)
basically what i want to return is **only**:

```
+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
| Id | Name |       Start        |        End         | Active |
+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
|  1 | John | 10-June 2019 08:00 | 10-June 2019 16:00 | true   |
|  2 | Stan | 10-June 2019 12:00 | 10-June 2019 18:00 | true   |
|  3 | Kim  | 10-June 2019 16:00 | 11-June 2019 00:00 | true   |
|  2 | Stan | 11-June 2019 08:00 | 11-June 2019 16:00 | true   |
+----+------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+
```

I have tried the following code in the Controller, but I cant seem to be able to return the Data-set i want

```cs
private readonly DatabaseContext context;

public ManageUsersController(DatabaseContext Dbcontext)
{
    context = Dbcontext;
}

[HttpGet("Users")]
public List<Employee> GetUsers()
{
    var data = context.Employee.Include(c=> c.Schedule).toList();
    return data;
}
```

The models i retrieve the data looks like this

```
public partial class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PhoneNr { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        //Relationship
        public ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public partial class Schedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } //EmployeeId
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End{ get; set; }
        public bool? Active { get; set; }

        //Relationship
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
```

lastly my DatabaseContext file looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

}
```

Hope my question isn't to long, and thanks in advance for the response

Comment: So you are saying that you want to filter data of the "Shift" table? If yes what kind of filter you want to add... date,name or ?

Comment: What data you require to filter is it based on any where condition. you can user where after include function.

Comment: I want to combine the tables into a single table, much like you would do in SQL with the following code: 
"Select e.ID, e.Name, s.Start, s.End, s.Active 
inner join Schedule s on s.Id = e.Id
From Employee e  "

Comment: @Steinar have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485360/linq-query-to-select-data-from-table-and-join-2-tables

Comment: @dimmik Thanks ! Have been looking for something like this for at least 2 days now !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @dimmik answered in the Comments on the question, it is possible to return the data by using Linq In my case this would be:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public List<EmployeeTable> GetUsers()
{
    var d = from e in context.Employee
        join s in context.Schedule on e.Id equals s.EmployeeId
        select new
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            Phone = e.PhoneNr,
            Mail = e.Mail,
            State = e.Active
        };
    return (List<EmployeeTable>)(Object)d.ToList();
}
```

EmployeeTable, is a custom class i created that has Id, Name, Phone, Mail and State as a property

Answer (score 2):

Create another class which will contain only the necessary properties.

```
public class EmployeeWithScheduleModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public DateTime Start {get;set;}
    public DateTime End {get;set;}
    public bool? Active {get;set;}
}
```

Then modify your controller method in order to return only what's necessary:

```
public List<EmployeeWithScheduleModel> GetUsers()
{
    var data = context.Employee.Include(c=>c.Schedule).ToList();

    var response = new List<EmployeeWithScheduleModel>();

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if(!item.Schedule.Any() || item.Schedule.Count > 1) continue; //your custom logic here

       var schedule = item.Schedule.FirstOrDefault();


       var employeeWithSchedule = new EmployeeWithScheduleModel
       {
          Id = item.Id,
          Name = item.Name,
          Start = schedule.Start,
          End = schedule.End,
          Active = schedule.Active
       };

       response.Add(employeeWithSchedule);
    }     

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet("Users")]
public List<EmployeeTable> GetUsers()
{
var empDetails=context.Employee.join(context.Schedule,e=>e.Id,d=>d.Id,(e,d)=>new {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            Start = d.Start,
            End = d.End,
            Active = d.Active
return (List<EmployeeTable>)(Object)empDetails.ToList();
});
}
```