# join two tables with multiple condition in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LinQ and have some issues while executing a Linq statement. Below is the summary of the same.

I have two class objects with same class type, eg: Report r1, Report r2 which has values like month, ID, values. values are different for both objects. eg:

```
List<Report> r1 = new List<Report>();
List<Report> r2 = new List<Report>();

        r1.Add(new Report { month = 1, ID = 1, a = 5, b = 12 });
        r1.Add(new Report { month = 1, ID = 2, a = 6, b = 13 });
        r1.Add(new Report { month = 2, ID = 1, a = 6, b = 14 });
        r1.Add(new Report { month = 2, ID = 2, a = 8, b = 15 });
        r1.Add(new Report { month = 3, ID = 2, a = 9, b = 16 });


        r2.Add(new Report { month = 1, ID = 1, a = 5, b = 22 });
        r2.Add(new Report { month = 1, ID = 2, a = 6, b = 23 });
        r2.Add(new Report { month = 2, ID = 1, a = 6, b = 24 });


        var delreport =
                            from rr1 in r1
                            join rr2 in r2 on new { rr1.month, rr1.ID }
                            equals new { rr2.month, rr2.ID } into result
                            select result;
```

However, I am getting blank result set. I am expecting to get r2 data (a, b values) matching with **month** and **id** of r1 along with r1 data (a, b values).
hope, my question is clear, request your help.

Comment: does this answer help you at all? I believe the relevant part is the new anonymous object as the select statements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433/creating-a-linq-select-from-multiple-tables

Comment: if you want values both table where month and id match then write condition like a.Month equals b.ID in your Linq join

Comment: @RajkumarDorkhande he is attempting to match on two columns in this case.  He wants `rr1.month equals rr2.month and rr1.ID equals rr2.ID`

Comment: after he edit question i write a comment to change condition as now i edit answer

Comment: @AaronRoberts - this looks relevant to me. Let me try this snippet in my code.

Comment: are you also expecting to sum the values of r1(a and b) to r2(a and b)?

Comment: @RamjeeGupta - It's unclear to me how you're asking to combine the `a` and `b` data from the respective lists when there is a match.

Comment: @RamjeeGupta - Also, are you wanting to ignore the `month`/`ID` combinations that are not shared with both lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
var innerJoin =
    from rr1 in r1
    join rr2 in r2 on new {rr1.Month, rr1.ID} equals new {rr2.Month, rr2.ID}
    select new { R1 = rr1, R2 = rr2 };
```

the new anonymous object can be any type and has access to any properties that are available for the two collections being joined.

For a left outer join this is how it would be done

```
var leftJoin = 
    from rr1 in r1
    join rr2 in r2 on new {rr1.Month, rr1.ID} equals new {rr2.Month, rr2.ID} into ps
    from rr2 in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { R1 = rr1, R2 = rr2 };
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Can you please help with left outer join for the same case. I wanted to see all rows of r1 dataset with r2 values for matching and 0 value for non-matching results.

Comment: please see this answer for a left outer join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Answer (score 3):

This is the chain version of your query.

```
var delreport= r1.Join(r2, l => l.ID, r => r.ID, (l, r) => new { lft = l, rght = r })
    .Where(x => x.lft.month == x.rght.month)
    .Select(_ => new{ _.rght.ID, _.rght.month}).ToList();
```

It is tested and works with your data.

Comment: this is much less readable than the linq syntax he is using, why would he switch to this instead?

Comment: @AaronRoberts I like doing everything in chains

Comment: sure, but the OP is using a different syntax. I would suggest using the same syntax to answer the question since using one over the other in your case is opinion based.

Comment: @AaronRoberts OP has **used** the syntax however did not **ask** for an answer with the same syntax. Since his is not working, he might want to use a working statement. Its up to him.

Comment: @0014 - But this doesn't work. When I use the OP's data and your query I just get syntax errors. Did you test this?

Comment: @Enigmativity OP has edited his question, please refer to the edit section then perhaps you will understand why I wrote my statement this way. There should not be any syntax errors other than the table names...

Comment: @0014 - His variable names don't appear to have changed between edits.

Comment: @0014 - Also your use of `Month` rather than `month` is causing an error.

Comment: @0014 - Why have you got `.Select(_ => _)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited my question. Good catch with the syntax error on Month instead of month. The code was inefficient but working. Now I reduced the complexity.

Comment: @0014 - It's now not returning any of the `a` and `b` values that the OP was after. Are you testing this before posting?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes it is tested, however you dont get it. The statement that was posted was based on the only query before the **edit** of OPs. Now click on edit and look at the template linq query OP has posted. It is returning **new { rr2.month, rr2.ID } into result** which means my answer is suppose to return what it is returning now. With that much of rep you have I cant understand how you cant think of these. If you want to know how to add a and b into my return statement just add them in the select.  `new{ _.rght.ID, _.rght.month, _.rght.a, _.rght.b}` thats it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to join two table with some same of one column fkid is same then used following code two join both table and access to get desired result otherwise ignore.

following **db** is the database entities object.

Note: In your code you join different entities month and id are different in data that reason you get empty result used following code

```
var v = (from a in db.r1.ToList()
         join b in db.r2.ToList() on a.Month equals b.ID

         select new
          {
            Id = a.ID,
            month = b.Month // or a.Month as you want,
            values = a.values
          });
```

by using these you access both table value and get accepted result. thank if it is usable for you.

Comment: I want to get r2 value only when (ID and month) matches for both lists.

Comment: yes Ramjee if write condition a.month equals b.id and access b.month or b.id then you select values from r2

Comment: you are matching (a.Month equals b.ID).. However, I will test this code to see my desired result