# Change sql query to linq in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to change sql query to linq using join statement. The query should retrieve columns (`days` and `startdate`) while matching records of table 1 to table. In short converting sql query to linq using join statement.

Below is what i've tried.

SQL Query (Working)

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo."Batches" 
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentBatchRelation 
      on dbo.Batches.Id = dbo.StudentBatchRelation.BatchId 
WHERE 
      dbo.StudentBatchRelation.StudentId = '3d980306-e36e-4581-8c98-219717cb1668'
```

LINQ (not fetching result)

```
var result = (from t1 in contBatch.GetallBatchList()
              join t2 in contStudent.getAllStudentBatchList() 
                   on t1.Id equals t2.batchId where t2.studentId == studentid
              select new { t1.Days, t1.BatchDate }).ToList();
```

Comment: try without the select

Comment: A query must end with a select clause or group clause

Comment: @user100020, try select new {t1, t2}
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433/creating-a-linq-select-from-multiple-tables

Comment: If you look at my question, I've done the same thing

Comment: do you get errors or not?

Comment: No i don't get any error. I see my query is fine to work, it just that i wasn't calling batchid in getAllStudentBatchList method.

Comment: Define proper relations and navigation properties and you won't need any joins.

Comment: @user100020 if my answer helps you, please feel free to accept it to close the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your EF entities are well defined, you could simplify your query with :

```
var result = Db.Batches
               .Include(p => p.StudentBatchRelation)
               .Where(p => p.StudentBatchRelation.StudentId = "3d980306-e36e-4581-8c98-219717cb1668")
               .ToList();
```

Otherwise, if you have to use your `Getallxxxx` functions, you could do :

```
var result = (from t1 in contBatch.GetallBatchList()
              join t2 in contStudent.getAllStudentBatchList()
                     on t1.Id equals t2.batchId 
              where t2.studentId == "3d980306-e36e-4581-8c98-219717cb1668"
              select t1)
              .ToList();
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to what I've done already as mentioned in my question.